# Get value for cookie connect.sid key in Express Node.js

Tags: node.js, session, express, socket.io

I'm creating a session for an auth'd user and then getting socket.io to send me the connect.sid cookie value, which I want to find the correlating value to auth the socket client.

Does anyone know how to get the value of connect.sid key in Express?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you can get the sessionID with `request.sessionID`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread useful: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/issues/588

Connect offers a method to parse the signed cookie:

```
var cookieValue = connect.utils.parseSignedCookies(cookie, sessionKey);
```

You can reference the connect module directly from within express.